# setting height for intermediate <li>

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am using *Bootstrap 3.2* menu my first 2 `li` and last 2 `li` is static and intermediate menu may be from 0 to 10-15 or more.
my problem is due to dynamic `li` my menu length is large.
I want to set minimum height for my dynamically generated menu  user can scroll to see more menu list( only for dynamic) static menu `li` shoul visible without any scroll.

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
      <li>Menu 1</li>
      <li>Menu 2</li>
     <li>Menu 3</li>
     <li>Menu 4</li>
     <li>Menu 5</li>
     <li>Menu 6</li>
    .....
     <li>Menu n-1</li>
     <li>Menu n</li>
    </ul>
```

How to do this??

Comment: wait so you want to set height for the first and last two, or the items in between?

Comment: If none of the answers worked or you are still facing trouble, let me know so I can help

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery [slice()](https://api.jquery.com/slice/) like

```
$('.dropdown-menu li').slice(2, $('.dropdown-menu li').length - 2).height();
```

Update

> It should show 2-3 'li` and after that to see other li ther should be
>   scrollbar

```
var targetHeight = $('.dropdown-menu').height() / 5;
$('.dropdown-menu li').slice(2, 2 + 3).height(targetHeight);
$('.dropdown-menu').css('overflow', 'scroll');
```

Comment: @Beginner, if he wants the first and last 2, no it shouldnt

Comment: Yes it is working to select. but I am unable to set height feature. It should show 2-3 'li` and after that to see other `li` ther should be scrollbar